# Get a control inside another control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been racking my brain over this for a while, its been a while since I had to do this and know its possible I've done it in another project in the past that I don't have a backup of to refer to.

I have a Login View on a page inside the login view is 2 panels one panel with a login control (to login) and one panel with a createuserwizard (to register) and a second button to click to register.

I'm trying to hide the panel with the login control and show the panel with the register control via a button click but all I end up with is a null reference exception.

this is what I have currently.

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindControl("LoginView1").FindControl("LoginPanel").Visible = false;
    FindControl("LoginView1").FindControl("RegPanel").Visible = true;
}
```

I appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Can this answer solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047647/113794

Comment: it would but the way I did in my answer below uses way less code. I only needed it to work in a single page, had I needed this in many pages the other one would be good as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was so I'll leave the question here for anyone who may have the same problem and stumble across this

I was so used to working with controls from a master page but within a page that's inside the master page you don't need the first findcontrol its simply:

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginView1.FindControl("LoginPanel").Visible = false;
    LoginView1.FindControl("RegPanel").Visible = true;
}
```